# Relation between products of groups and matrix representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, soft-question, representation-theory, tensor-products

I have done a little bit of abstract algebra with groups. Most of it relates to rather practically oriented applications in engineering like rotation groups, permutations, affine transformations. For these purposes we have a tool known as **representation theory**, where a group representation is a mapping between every group element and a matrix, in such a way that matrix multiplication between these matrices correspond to the group operation:

$$ab=c \Leftrightarrow {\bf M_a M_b = M_c}, \forall a,b,c \in G$$

Furthermore I know there exists a concept of **product** between groups.

Now to the question, given two matrix representations with representation matrices $$\{\bf M_{1k}\},\{M_{2l}\}$$ for any two elements in their respective groups $$k\in G_1, l\in G_2$$

Can we construct a matrix representation for the product of these groups straight away from these $\{\bf M_{1k}\},\{\bf M_{2l}\}$ ?

---

**My suspicion** is that some kind of  tensor product should allow us to do this, but I have no proof.

Comment: Simply consider matrices $\begin{pmatrix}M_{1k}&0\\0&M_{2k}\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @JeanMarie : Nice, this is something like I suspected! How nice and easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is often called the *outer tensor product* of representations. If we state each representation as group homomorphisms $\phi: G \to \mathrm{GL}_n$ and $\psi: H \to \mathrm{GL}_m$, then we can construct a representation of $G \times H$ on the tensor product space $V = \mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^m$ by setting the group element $(g, h)$ to act by $\phi(g) \otimes \psi(h)$. In terms of matrices, this is called the *kronecker product* of the matrices $\phi(g)$ and $\psi(h)$.

Comment: Ah so it also works with Kronecker products! Faschinating! Thank you.

Comment: I should point out that all of the irreducible representations of $G \times H$ arise using this construction when $\phi$ and $\psi$ are irreducible representations of $G$ and $H$ individually. You can also define a kind of "direct sum" representation as in one of the comments to your question, but not all irreducibles arise that way.